# SQL Editor window always connects to (localdb\ProjectsV13). Where to change this default?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

**Context**

I am using a Database project in VS 2015 update 2. When I open a .sql script file the editor windows is in disconnected state. When I simply click on connect on the toolbar it keeps connecting the (localdb)\ProjectsV13 so I have to click on the toolbar on the Change Connection to change it. Even I am saving, nothing remembered, this process have to be repeated for *all* my .sql files each time.

**Question**

How can I persist and remember my connection preference for all my .sql scripts in this database project?

**Exhibit**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Project > Properties > Debug > Target Connection String
```

Ref: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272681(v=vs.103).aspx#bkmk_debug)

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried to found this setting by mass method: I simply searched the file system all files for ProjectsV13  (a part of the bad connection string and it was not found... Now I am seeing it in the location you pointed. It is a default somewhere else (or hardcoded). Anyway here I can overwrite